# Manifest merger failed with multiple errors, see logs (Bumblebee)

Tags: android, android-studio, build.gradle, android-manifest

I am facing this error "Manifest merger failed with multiple errors, see logs". I already tried rebuilding, and cleaning project and have also gone through the Merged Manifest file(as suggested in another similar type of question) but can't find the error.
How can i solve this problem? What should i do now?

build.gradle(app)

```
 plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
}

android {
    compileSdk 32

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.instagram"
        minSdk 21
        targetSdk 32
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    buildFeatures{
        viewBinding true
    }
}

dependencies {

    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.4.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.5.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.3'
    implementation 'com.github.iammert:ReadableBottomBar:0.2'
    implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
    implementation 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:3.1.0'
    implementation 'com.github.MrNouri:DynamicSizes:1.0'
    implementation 'com.makeramen:roundedimageview:2.3.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.3'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.4.0'
}
```

Maifest File

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="com.example.instagram">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"

        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.Instagram">
    <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

And Merged Mainfest
[Merged Mainfest](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xbLBN.png)

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

you try to add `tools:replace="android:allowBackup"` to  element at app AndroidManifest.

Comment: Still facing the same issue

Comment: hey, add `android.enableJetifier=true` to `gradle.properties` file. `com.github.MrNouri:DynamicSizes:1.0` is using support libray that replace with androidx. so you must to migrate to androidX https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/migrate